# Probability that one person's weight is more than 50 pounds greater than another's

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

The weight of a Portuguese man is normally distributed with mean 160 pounds and standard deviation 30 pounds.  The weight of a Portuguese woman is normally distributed with mean 120 pounds and standard deviation 25 pounds.  If a Portuguese man and a Portuguese woman are each randomly chosen.  What is the probability that the man's weight is more than 50 lbs greater than the woman's?

My thought was to standardize both of the normal distributions and convert the probability $P(M>W+50)$ into an expression involving only $Z$.  But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: Can you write something about the distribution of the difference in their weights ($M-W$)? Can you then cast the desired probability in terms of that?

Comment: If you are willing to make the assumption that $M$ and $W$ are _independent_ (normal) random variables, then you can use a fact that follows from such an assumption, namely, that  $M-W$ is a normal random variable with mean $160-120 = 40$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{30^2+25^2} \approx 39.05$, and proceed to determine $P(M-W>50)$ using your favorite $z$-score.